# google tag not firing when clicking <strong> tag in an <a>

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I have a button:

```
<a href="#how-it-works" class="purple-button text-center">LEARN HOW <strong>BREATH<br>POWERED DELIVERY</strong> WORKS</a>
```

We are using google tag manager on this button and if we click any of the area that is inside the `<strong>` element, the GTM event does not fire. If I click anywhere else it is fine and the event is sent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The strong element was taking focus priority over the anchor element thus not firing. Setting `.purple-button strong { pointer-events:none;}` fixed it.

Note that `pointer-events` is not supported in < IE10. All other browsers seem to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick handler to the "strong" element that scrolls to that anchor.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The href is what scrolls to the anchor. What would I do in the onclick? You mean an onclick to the strong tag?

Comment: I figured it out. The strong element was taking focus priority over the anchor element thus not firing. Setting `.purple-button strong { pointer-events:none;}` fixed it.

Comment: @Ronnie you should answer your question yourself and accept it because this answer suggest to use `onclick` and that is something different.

Answer (score 0):

This is often a problem with Google Tag Manager. If you were trying to solve it without editing the site code, you could use a custom JavaScript element to read attributes from the parent, allowing you to set up a similar trigger to that presumably used for the rest of the button.

```
function() {
return {{Click Element}}.parentElement.href;
}
```